# Install apache module with puppet on Debian 7

Tags: apache, vagrant, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

My problem is during the provisionning of my Vagrant VM using puppet. The error is :

> ==> default: err: /Stage[main]//Service[apache2]: Could not evaluate: Could not find init script for 'apache2'

My puppetFile  is the following default.pp :

```
Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }

exec { 'apt-get update':
    command => 'apt-get update',
    timeout => 60,
    tries   => 3
}

class { 'apt': }

$sysPackages = ['python-software-properties', 'build-essential', 'apache2', 'apache2.2-common']
    package { $sysPackages:
    ensure => "installed",
    require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

service { apache2:
    ensure  => running,
    enable  => true,
    require => Package['apache2', 'apache2.2-common'],
}
```

When not writting the apache2 service, there is no error thrown, but there is no `/etc/init.d/apache2`. I guess that's why the error is thrown. So how can I avoid this error, or more generaly how to cleanly install this module ?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Consider using apache module for puppet :  https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache

Comment: Your code looks fine. No wrong.

Comment: There's no need to include apache2.2-common. Use "sudo apt-cache depends apache2" and you'll see that apache2.2-common will automagically be installed as well.

Comment: @kkamilpl Good advice, installing the module with `puppet module install` showed me there was a dependency to a 'concat' module I did not know existed. However the problem still exists.

Comment: And thank you @mlambrichs for this very true observation.